# R: Relate output of forecast::tsclean() back to original dataframe by datetime

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, outliers

I am trying to remove established outliers from a time-series dataframe using the `tsclean()` function from the `forecast` package.

In order to use `tsclean()`, I've converted my raw data into a `ts()` object. Unfortunately, this deletes my timestamp vector which is creating some problems later on. After feeding my `ts()` object into the `tsclean()` function, a properly cleaned time-series is returned. However, I cannot join this result back to my original dataframe since the `POSIXct` timestamp no longer exists within my `tsclean()` object. I am ultimately trying to perform a `lm()` on the cleaned response variable, `df$Y`, against an explanatory variable, `df$X`, within my original dataframe.

```
library(forecast)
datetime <- as.POSIXct(c("2018-03-05 15:54:00", "2018-03-05 15:55:00", "2018-03-05 15:56:00", "2018-03-05 15:57:00", "2018-03-05 15:58:00"))
Y <- c(1, 5, 9, 100, 2)
X <- c(3, 4, 2, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(datetime, Y, X)
time_series <- ts(df$Y)
time_series_clean <- tsclean(time_series)
```

**Original dataframe:**

```
             datetime   Y X
1 2018-03-05 15:54:00   1 3
2 2018-03-05 15:55:00   5 4
3 2018-03-05 15:56:00   9 2
4 2018-03-05 15:57:00 100 4
5 2018-03-05 15:58:00   2 5
```

**Desired result:**

```
             datetime   Y X
1 2018-03-05 15:54:00   1 3
2 2018-03-05 15:55:00   5 4
3 2018-03-05 15:56:00   9 2
4 2018-03-05 15:58:00   2 5
```

**Before `tsclean()`:**

[image]

**After `tsclean()`:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you want to remove outliers from the original data.  A solution is to use the `tsoutliers` function:

```
time_series_outliers <- tsoutliers(time_series) # identify outliers
df <- df[-time_series_outliers$index, ] # remove them from the original data
```

This function is also interesting, giving `$replacements` if you desire the suggested value to replace the outliers.

Comment: This was a totally different approach to using `tsclean()`, but I'm happy with the result. Thanks for showing me how to filter my original df by the `time_series_outliers$index`!